# How to mount a Windows 10 partition?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Alright, so I'm a total linux noob. However, I'm having trouble with a Windows machine and want to use Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to figure out how to fix it. I've made a bootable USB drive and managed to convince Windows to let me boot from it. Everything is going well so far. However, I'm rather inept when it comes to using Linux, and can't seem to make heads or tail out of how to get the terminal to do anything.

In order to perform the test I'm wanting to perform, I need to mount my windows partition. When I try to do that through the GUI, I get a message that says:

> Unable to access "Windows"
>
> error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/ubuntu/windows: Command-line 'mount
>   -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodef,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda4" "/media/ubuntu/Windows"' exited with non-zero exit status
>   14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount
>   'dev/sda4': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe
>   state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or
>   fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount
>   option.

Deciding that booting up Windows, then shutting it down would take a very very long time (due to the issue I'm trying to fix), I decided to try mounting the drive as read-only, so I typed the following into the terminal:

> sudo mount -ro -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodef,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda4" "/media/ubuntu/Windows"

This produced what looks likes information on the command itself that is basically indecipherable to me, and did not mount the drive. What am I doing wrong, and how to I do this one very simple thing?

Comment: Linux is kernel common in a wide range of operating system, including Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not a tool to fix Windows. In this case It can at most be useful as dfescribe above in the possible duplicate.

Comment: The instructions there fixed my problem! Thank you!

Comment: As for why I'm trying to use Ubuntu to try and fix Windows, I'm more using it as a tool for identifying the problem. If the problem is hardware-related, it will persist in Ubuntu, but if Ubuntu has no problem doing what I need, then it's a software problem.